# how do keep sequelizer from dropping a database

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js

I've been going through some examples with sequelizer and they all drop the database upon launching the app. How do I get the database to persist between instances of the app?

Answer (score 1):

So I found another thread with the answer. if you want your database to persist remove {force true} from the following line:
db.sequelize.sync({force true}).then...